# Parameter string is null when passed to controller from datatable

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am new in MVC. So this might be a stupid question from me.

I am trying to send parameter to my controller, but i did not get the value. Can someone help me what did i do wrong?

The username that is passed in the controller is always null. From the example that i follow it is using integer as the parameter. When i use id i will get the parameter. But when i pass string then i will get null value. Please help me. Thank you.

Here is the view

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        dataTable = $("#batchTable").DataTable({
            "ajax": {
                "url": "/Home/GetDPUserList",
                "type": "POST",
                "datatype": "json"
            },

            "columns": [
                { "data": "Username", "name":"Username" },
                { "data": "Name", "name": "Name"  },
                { "data": "Email", "name": "Email"  },
                { "data": "IsAdmin", "name": "IsAdmin" },
                {
                    "data": "Username", "render": function (data) {
                        return "<a class='btn btn-default btn-sm' onclick=EditUserForm('@Url.Action("UpdateUser","Home")/" + data +"')><i class='fa fa-pencil'></i> Edit</a><a class='btn btn-danger btn-sm'  style='margin-left: 5px' onclick=Delete(" + data +")><i class='fa fa-trash'></i> Delete</a>";
                    },
                    "orderable": false,
                    "searchable": false,
                    "width": "150px"
                },

            ],

            "processing": "true",
            "serverSide": "true",
            "order": [0, "asc"]
        });
    });

function EditUserForm(url) {
        alert(url)
        var formDiv = $('<div/>');

        $.get(url)
            .done(function (response) {
                formDiv.html(response);



                popup = formDiv.dialog({
                    autoOpen: true,
                    resizable: false,
                    title: "Add New User",
                    height: 410,
                    width: 300,
                    close: function () {
                        popup.dialog('destroy').remove();
                    }
                });
            });
    }
```

Here is the controller

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult UpdateUser(string username = "")
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(username))
        {
            return View(new DP_User());
        }
        else
        {
            using (DBModel db = new DBModel())
            {
                return View(db.DP_User.Where(x => x.Username == username).FirstOrDefault<DP_User>());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Pass username as querystring instead of Parameter. Because default mvc route expects the variable name as `id` and you are using `username`

Comment: it is as Manprit said. Default mvc route expects the variable name as id. You can refer in Route.Config. I have changed my table to use id instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add route in Route.Config

```
routes.MapRoute(
         name: "namesomething",/// as per your naming convention 
         url: "Home/UpdateUser/{username}",
         defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "UpdateUser", username = UrlParameter.Optional }
      );
```

Comment: Thank you for this info. But i have decided to change my Table to pass id to follow default mvc route.